# Unzip file in Gradle using Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Groovy Gradle script that I need to convert over to Kotlin DSL. Below is an abridged version of the source build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        runtimeDir = "$buildDir/dependencies/fooBarRuntime"
    }
}

...

configurations {
    runtimeArchive
}

dependencies {   
    runtimeArchive "foo:bar:1.2.3@zip"
}

task unzip(type: Copy) {
    configurations.runtimeArchive.asFileTree.each {
        from(zipTree(it))
    }
    into runtimeDir
}

test.dependsOn unzip

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    environment "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", runtimeDir
}
```

Where I am coming unstuck is finding a clear example on how to do this via Kotlin DSL (I have check the [Kotlin DSL docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) and [Offical Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html).

Some part are obvious, declare `val runtimeDir  by extra("$buildDir/dependencies/fooBarRuntime")` instead, but what's mostly tripping me up is the zip dependency and the extraction into a known location for later use.

Can anyone point me towards an example/documentation?

**Update:**

I've now got something like this, and it seems to work:

```
val fooBarRuntime by configurations.creating
val runtimeDir  by extra("$buildDir/dependencies/fooBarRuntime")

dependencies {
    fooBarRuntime("foo", "bar", "1.2.3" , ext="zip")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    dependsOn("unzip")
}

tasks.register("unzip") {
    fooBarRuntime.asFileTree.forEach {
        unzipTo(File(runtimeDir), it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:
    val fooBarRuntime by configurations.creating
    val runtimeDir  by extra("$buildDir/dependencies/fooBarRuntime")

```
dependencies {
    fooBarRuntime("foo", "bar", "1.2.3" , ext="zip")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    dependsOn("unzip")
}

tasks.register("unzip") {
    fooBarRuntime.asFileTree.forEach {
        unzipTo(File(runtimeDir), it)
    }
}
```